# Android Studio Java, Can't manage to output both fo the data

Tags: java, android

im having issues with my code.  I having issues with displaying both exchange rates and currency name near them from the api. Does someone have any advice or can help? I managed to figure out how to output the currency value from the api, but cant seem to figure out how to output the name aswell.
Thank you Very much in advance!

MainActivity

```
package com.example.currencyapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mCurrencies;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    private android.widget.ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCurrencies = findViewById(R.id.currencies);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        adapter = new CoinsAdapter(this);
        mCurrencies.setAdapter(adapter);
        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                jsonParse();

            }
        });

    }

    private void jsonParse() {
        String url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                response -> {
                    java.util.List<String> dataList = parser(response);
                    adapter.clear();
                    adapter.addAll(dataList);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }, error -> error.printStackTrace());
        mQueue.add(request);
    }

    List<String> parser(JSONObject response) {
        HashMap<String, String> currencies = new HashMap<>();
        JSONObject exchangeRates = response.optJSONObject("rates");
        Iterator<String> keys = exchangeRates.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            String value = exchangeRates.optString(key);
            currencies.put(key, value);
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(currencies.values());
    }
}
```

CoinsAdapter.java

```
package com.example.currencyapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

class CoinsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public CoinsAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        String item = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView tvName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.currency_row_textView);
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        tvName.setText(item);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/currencies"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="597dp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
        android:text="parse" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currency_row_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:text="30.0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to show both currency name and value.
   so  you will change the parse method like this:

```
   public List<String> parser(JSONObject response) {
           List<String> currencies = new ArrayList<>();
           JSONObject exchangeRates = response.optJSONObject("rates");
           Iterator<String> keys = exchangeRates.keys();
           while (keys.hasNext()) {
               String key = keys.next();
               String value = exchangeRates.optString(key);
               currencies.add(key + ": " + value);
           }
           return new ArrayList<>(currencies);
       }
```

2. You have define dataList in Globally like:

```
public List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

3. some changes on JsonParse method whenever you call api.

```
private void jsonParse() {
        String url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                response -> {
                    adapter.clear();
                    dataList = parser(response);
                    adapter.addAll(dataList);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }, error -> error.printStackTrace());
        mQueue.add(request);
    }
```

4. I this code working properly I am showing output below.
   [image]